# How do you merge two git branches that are in different local repos/folders?

Tags: git

I have:

```
folder_a/app_1.0
folder_b/app_1.1
```

And let's just say I'm working off of the master branch in both folders/repos.

How can I merge the branches together?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You must pull the commits from one repository into the other, do the merge, then pull back into the first (if you want both repositories to contain all the commits).

```
# switch to repo A
cd folder_a

# Add repo B as a remote repository
git remote add folderb /path/to/folder_b

# Pull B's master branch into a local branch named 'b'
git pull folderb master:b

# Merge b into A's master branch
git merge b

# Switch to repo B
cd ../folder_b

# Add repo A as a remote repository
git remote add foldera /path/to/folder_a

# Pull the resulting branch into repo B's master branch
git pull foldera master:master
```

Comment: Since folder_b is not a bare repository, you shouldn't push into it. You should add folder_a as a remote and pull from it.

Comment: You're right, of course. I updated to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: What if repo A has a different folder structure than repo B?

Comment: @7537247 in this case, let assume main branch is master in repo A.
- in repo A we need to create a pull request from B's master branch - b to A's master to prevent conflict and overwritten code

Comment: You might need to include `--allow-unrelated-histories` when merging  `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories b`